# #Error even after using IIF to avoid division by Zero in Expression

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder3.0

Ran into this issue in SSRS and am hoping for some assistance.

Simply want to return a 0 or 0.00 in a Total textbox when there is a zero in textbox 167 or 168. I have ISNULL covered in the dataset for both fields. Textbox is formatted Currency in Report. I'm getting results if 167 and 168  are both not 0, but #Error if they are. Any thoughts?

```
=IIF((ReportItems!Textbox167.Value > 0) AND (ReportItems!Textbox168.Value > 0)
    ,CDEC(ReportItems!Textbox173.Value / ReportItems!Textbox167.Value) - 
     CDEC(ReportItems!Textbox176.Value / ReportItems!Textbox168.Value), 0)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible they have NULL values?

Comment: Are you using Float number?

Answer (score 2):

**IIF** evaluates both possibilities even IF it doesn't need to - resulting in your error.

The theory is that you want the expression to evaluate normally if the denominator is not zero, but use 0 / 1 if the denominator is zero.

Your expression would look like:

```
=IIF(ReportItems!Textbox167.Value = 0, 0, CDEC(ReportItems!Textbox173.Value))
 /
 IIF(ReportItems!Textbox167.Value = 0, 1, CDEC(ReportItems!Textbox167.Value))
 -
 IIF(ReportItems!Textbox168.Value = 0, 0, CDEC(ReportItems!Textbox176.Value))
 / 
 IIF(ReportItems!Textbox168.Value = 0, 1, CDEC(ReportItems!Textbox168.Value))
```

Comment: Perfect... Solved my issue. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that IIF is not like the ternary operator in C# as an example, where the conditional expressions are only evaluated depending on the state of the boolean expression.

In other words, this:

```
=IIF(a, b, c)
```

Will first evaluate `a`, `b`, *and* `c`, before `IIF` is evaluated. The damage has already done by the time `IIF` gets to look at the values.

Instead you should bake the dividend into an `IIF` expression to ensure you will never get the `0` in the divide expression at all, instead of trying to avoid using the expression.